# How write program in c# (visual studio) which connects to the GPS USB port and display NMEA data in richTextBox?

Tags: c#, gps, usb, richtextbox

I have GPS on USB connections.

[image: GPSusb]

I use program Virtual GPS which automaticly search and connect withs this GPS and display NMEA data.

I want to write a simple program in C# which will be connect with this GPS and display NMEA data in RichTextBox in Real-Time.

I need help, because I don't know where and how to start. I'm beginner in c# but I'm determined because I dont have a lot of time. I'm working now on processing nmea data (and I wrote a large part of the program, which I needed to my school work (plot chart lang and latit, display routes, parse nmea itc)). I need tips, sample code, sample article or everything which can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most GPS mice for PCs are detected/recognized as a USB ACM/COM/Serial device.
That means they emulate a serial port. Have a look into your device-manager to find if thats the case and which COMx port it was connected to.

You can then use the SerialPort-class (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport(v=vs.110).aspx) to connect to the mouse.

A object of type SerialPort has the really nice event called "DataReceived", which is getting called when data arrives in the input buffer or (when set) when a new line of NMEA data has arrived.

Be aware that the DataReceived event gets triggered in a different thread than your GUI-thread and that you will need to invoke into your Windows-Form (or similar).

Answer (score 0):

Ok problem is resolved. Little change's **.ReadExisting(); -> .ReadLine();** and one another **.Invoke -> .BeginInvoke**. I found a lot of serial com program and nobody look at this problem .. In this change's isn't possible crash program when we stop (disconnect port) and again start etc.

```
private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        RxString = serialPort1.ReadLine();
        this.BeginInvoke(new EventHandler(DisplayText));
    }
```